# Strongly-Type view and Normal view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, strongly-typed-view

What are the differences between strongly-type view and normal view in asp.net MVC?

When I add a `View` by right click on my `Controller` into my asp.net MVC project, I have checked a checkbox named Create a strong-typed view. What are the things will change when I checked that checkbox?

Thanks.

Comment: It will add `@model yourModel` to the top of the view.

Comment: Thanks. Is that only?

Comment: Yes (and you can just do it manually)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With strongly typed views, your view file will have the following directive

```
@model YourModel
```

at the top of the file

This signifies to the view that `@Html` helpers and `@Model` helpers will interact with a class of that type.

For example

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyProperty)
```

Assuming `MyProperty` is a property on `YourModel` class.

You can create your views manually, and just add the `@model` directive at the top of the page yourself.